# npm installation error from the terminal while deploy node project

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, npm-package, npm-publish

i am facing while installing npm

```
root@thesoftwarecompany:~/backend# npm install
npm WARN deprecated csurf@1.11.0: Please use another csrf package
npm WARN deprecated request-promise-native@1.0.9: request-promise-native has bee                                                                                                             n deprecated because it extends the now deprecated request package, see https://                                                                                                             github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.1: The querystring API is considered Legacy.                                                                                                              new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
npm WARN deprecated exec@0.2.1: deprecated in favor of builtin child_process.exe                                                                                                             cFile
npm WARN deprecated debug@4.1.1: Debug versions >=3.2.0 <3.2.7 || >=4 <4.3.1 hav                                                                                                             e a low-severity ReDos regression when used in a Node.js environment. It is reco                                                                                                             mmended you upgrade to 3.2.7 or 4.3.1. (https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/iss                                                                                                             ues/797)
npm WARN deprecated debug@4.1.1: Debug versions >=3.2.0 <3.2.7 || >=4 <4.3.1 hav                                                                                                             e a low-severity ReDos regression when used in a Node.js environment. It is reco                                                                                                             mmended you upgrade to 3.2.7 or 4.3.1. (https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/iss                                                                                                             ues/797)
npm WARN deprecated debug@4.1.1: Debug versions >=3.2.0 <3.2.7 || >=4 <4.3.1 hav                                                                                                             e a low-severity ReDos regression when used in a Node.js environment. It is reco                                                                                                             mmended you upgrade to 3.2.7 or 4.3.1. (https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/iss                                                                                                             ues/797)
npm WARN deprecated mkdirp@0.3.5: Legacy versions of mkdirp are no longer suppor                                                                                                             ted. Please update to mkdirp 1.x. (Note that the API surface has changed to use                                                                                                              Promises in 1.x.)
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older v                                                                                                             ersions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be pro                                                                                                             blematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://git                                                                                                             hub.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated bcrypt@3.0.8: versions < v5.0.0 do not handle NUL in passwor                                                                                                             ds properly
npm WARN deprecated messageformat@2.3.0: Package renamed as '@messageformat/core                                                                                                             ', see messageformat.github.io for more details. 'messageformat@4' will eventual                                                                                                             ly provide a polyfill for Intl.MessageFormat, once it's been defined by Unicode                                                                                                              & ECMA.
npm WARN deprecated node-pre-gyp@0.14.0: Please upgrade to @mapbox/node-pre-gyp:                                                                                                              the non-scoped node-pre-gyp package is deprecated and only the @mapbox scoped p                                                                                                             ackage will recieve updates in the future
npm WARN deprecated express-fileupload@0.3.0: Please upgrade express-fileupload                                                                                                              to version 1.1.8+ due to a security vulnerability with the parseNested option
npm WARN deprecated tar@2.2.2: This version of tar is no longer supported, and w                                                                                                             ill not receive security updates. Please upgrade asap.
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /root/backend/node_modules/node-libcurl
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c -- node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
npm ERR! make: Entering directory '/root/backend/node_modules/node-libcurl/build                                                                                                             '
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/node_libcurl/src/node_libcurl.o
npm ERR! make: Leaving directory '/root/backend/node_modules/node-libcurl/build'
npm ERR! Failed to execute '/root/.nvm/versions/node/v16.18.1/bin/node /root/.nv                                                                                                             m/versions/node/v16.18.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp                                                                                                             .js build --fallback-to-build --module=/root/backend/node_modules/node-libcurl/l                                                                                                             ib/binding/node_libcurl.node --module_name=node_libcurl --module_path=/root/back                                                                                                             end/node_modules/node-libcurl/lib/binding --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi                                                                                                              --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v93' (1)
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.